# How to add selected data from list to multiple select box?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to design a form,on which I want to select multiple data from list and then on button click I want to add that data to multiple checkbox.Please can anybody provide me any java script function or something else
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide codes in your question.

Comment: Use `listbox` array to retrieve all selected values which on submit will be stored in an array. Now with those values of array you can create check boxes with array values as label by looping over the array.

Answer (score -1):

As a start point try using jQuery.

HTML:

```
<select type="multiple" id="mylist">
<option value="1" selected="selected">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">three</option>
<option value="4">four</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">five</option>
<option value="6">six</option>
</select>

<div id="checkboxcontainer"></div>

<input type="button" id="clicker" value="clicker" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#clicker").click(function(){
        $("#checlboxcontainer").empty();
        $("#mylist option:selected").each(function(){
            $("#checlboxcontainer").append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="'+$(this).val()+'" /> '+ $(this).text() +' </label><br />');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hmmm... probably I misunderstood your question (the minus thing)